# Android Mockito java.lang.AssertionError:

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I just started using Mockito so I can perform unit testing on my android app. I'm not understand why I'm getting the following error:

Can anyone please tell me what am I missing here?

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :http://a/h/url
Actual   :null
  <Click to see difference>




at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
```

Test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class NewsItemWrapperTest {

    public static final String T_URL ="http://a/th/url";
    public static final String H_URL ="http://a/h/url";


    @Mock
    NewsItem newsItem;

    @Mock
    NewsItemWrapper newsItemWrapper;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        //initMocks(this);
        newsItemWrapper = new NewsItemWrapper(newsItem);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetThumbImageUrl() throws Exception {



        assertEquals(T_URL, newsItemWrapper.getThumbNailImage());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetHeroImageUrl() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(H_URL, newsItemWrapper.getHImage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your test case code.  I mean NewsItemWrapperTest

Comment: hi @sankyjain I added my test case. thanks for replying

Comment: where have you mocked newsItem? please add that part. Problem is newsItemWrapper.getHImage() is returning null. So we need to see how you have mocked things

Comment: hi @sankyjain I'm not sure exactly what you mean by where have you mocked newsItem?

Comment: this is all the code? If yes you should add all the method mockings. for eg you should mock newsItem.getMediaList() method and so on.

Comment: yes that is all  the code. I added the following at the top of my NewsItemWrapperTest classes and I'm still getting error:  @Mock
 List<NewsItem.Media.MediaMetadata> mediaMetadataList;


 public List<NewsItem.Media.MediaMetadata> getMediaMetadataList() {
  return mediaMetadataList;
 }

Comment: it doesnot work that way. i will give you small example.

Comment: Ok how to I Mock newsItem.getMediaList() ?

Comment: I have added this in my setup():  
 public void setUp() throws Exception {

  mediaList = newsItem.getMediaList();
  newsItemWrapper = new NewsItemWrapper(newsItem);


 }

Comment: and I added this at the top of my test class:  @Mock
 private List<NewsItem.Media> mediaList; but it still not working

Comment: see my example and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a example. Similarly you need to mock all methods.
You can also mock media object.

```
Media m1 = new Media();
Media m2 = new Media();

List<Media> mediaList = Arrays.asList(m1, m2);
when(newsItem.getMediaList()).thenReturn(mediaList);
```

Comment: thanks. I added this but I'm getting NullPointerException: @Before
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
  NewsItem.Media m1 = new NewsItem.Media();
  NewsItem.Media m2 = new NewsItem.Media();

  List<NewsItem.Media> mediaList = Arrays.asList(m1, m2);
  Mockito.when(newsItem.getMediaList()).thenReturn(mediaList);
  

  newsItemWrapper = new NewsItemWrapper(newsItem);


 }

Comment: Obviously it will return NullPointer exception. This was just a example you need to define Media object or mock it and then return all the function calls. I will suggest you to go through a mockito tutorial and see how it works

Answer (score 0):

Your `NewsItem newsItem;` is a mock. It basically does exactly nothing. Void methods will do nothing. Other methods will return null (or the apropriate default primitive value). So, in your case, the call to `newsItem.getMediaList()` will return null.

To change that, you have to tell your mock that it should do something, preferably in the `@Before` method, for example...

```
List<NewsItem.Media> mediaList = new ArrayList<>();
...put stuff in it
Mockito.when( newsItem.getMediaList() ).thenReturn( mediaList );
```

This tells your mock: "When the method getMediaList() is called on you (newsItem), return this list.". You can also tell your mock to throw an exception (to test error handling, for example), etc.

Remember: That's the job of mocks, to allow you to **simulate** a behavior. Without commands to simulate something, mock do nothing. Mocks allow you to easily create fake objects for dependencies (in this case, your code depends on the `NewsItem` and using a mock allows you to have a `NewsItem` that will behave exactly as you need it for your test situation, be it correctly or somehow faulty).

Comment: Thanks @ Florian Shaetz, I added this and still not working:  @Before
 public void setUp() throws Exception {


  List<NewsItem.Media> mediaList = new ArrayList<>();

  Mockito.when( newsItem.getMediaList() ).thenReturn (mediaList);


  newsItemWrapper = new NewsItemWrapper(newsItem);


 }

Comment: Your mediaList must obviously also contain items. Add stuff to it.